# Not able to set value in TextInputLayout using Android Studio after selecting an item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

I developed an android app that requires 3 cascading dropdownlists using TextInputLayouts and AutoComplete views. I am pulling the data from SQL and thru okhttp I receive the response and I array the results. The problem is that when I select an item from the list, it does not place the selected item in the view. Instead, it is placing some kind of hex string. I did not wire up the other two dropdownlists, so nothing is tied into it.

e.g.: com.testapp.testappmobilekotlin.model.VendorResponse@a3014fb

This is what is displayed when I select an option, "HVAC Supply"

Below is a snippet from the activity. I am assuming that my base adapter and api calls are fine since it is populating the array and the list as designed.

```
 private fun loadVendorList() {
    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        getSharedPreferences("sharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val tenantId: String? = sharedPreferences.getString("tenantId_KEY", null)
    val token: String? = sharedPreferences.getString("accessToken_KEY", null)

    // make API call
    val call = checkStockService.getVendorList(tenantId,
        "Bearer $token",
        tenantId?.toInt(),
        "application/json"
    )
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<VendorResult> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<VendorResult>,
            response: Response<VendorResult>
        ) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                vendorItemsArrayList = response.body()!!.result as ArrayList<VendorResponse>?

                // initialize adapter
                vendorAdapter = VendorRequestBaseAdapter(
                    this@CheckStockActivity,
                    R.layout.dropdown_item,
                    vendorItemsArrayList
                )

                val editTextFilledExposedDropdown =
                    findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.selectVendor)
                editTextFilledExposedDropdown.setAdapter(vendorAdapter)
            }
        }
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<VendorResult>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(this@CheckStockActivity, "error :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

Here is my XML layout where I house the TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ll_dropdown_search">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/selectVendor"
                android:layout_width="284dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Select Vendor"
                android:inputType="none" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my TextView

```
 <TextView
android:id="@+id/vendorName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextView"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textColor="@color/black"
android:textStyle="normal"
android:textSize="15sp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
/>
```

Below is what happens when I select, let's say, "HVAC Supply" From the list. Any guidance would be more than welcomed! Thanks.

[image: This is a snapshot of the view after I selected "HVAC Supply"]

Answer (score 1):

I'm here to answer my own question with the hope that it will help anyone else out there that runs into this problem. Using Kotlin, I realized that I have to set up an "OnItemClickListener" on the AutoCompleteTextView. So, using my model, I coded the following:

```
                     val selectVendorDropDown =
                    findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.selectVendor)
                selectVendorDropDown.setAdapter(vendorAdapter)

                selectVendorDropDown.onItemClickListener =
                    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

                        val selectedItem = parent.adapter.getItem(position) as VendorResponse?
                        if (selectedItem != null) {
                            selectVendorDropDown.setText(selectedItem.vendorName)
                        }
                    }
```

This snippet of code, now allows the selected item to be displayed in the textview of whichever view you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter must have implemented the filterable interface, so you can rewrite convertresulttostring to solve this problem.

```
override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    return object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence): FilterResults {
            val charString = charSequence.toString()
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            filterResults.values = charString
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(
            charSequence: CharSequence,
            filterResults: FilterResults
        ) {

        }

        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any): CharSequence? {
            return (resultValue as Selector).Title
        }
    }
}
```